# Mysql parou de funcionar

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Olá estou usando o MariaDB 10.2, executei o comando de TRUNCATE em uma tabela com 4 GB e o Mysql parou de funionar, não consigo mais acessar qualquer outro banco de dados, estou usando o Mysql no xampp e ele apresenta a seguinte mensagem:

> 2018-11-12 11:28:18 8748 [ERRO] [FATAL] InnoDB: A página [page id: space = 6277, número da página = 16384] não pode ser lida no buffer pool após 100 tentativas. A causa mais provável desse erro pode ser que a tabela tenha sido corrompida. Ou a tabela estava repleta de um algoritmo que não é suportado por essa instância. Se não for uma falha de descompactação, você pode tentar corrigir esse problema usando innodb_force_recovery. Vamos tentar o nosso melhor para obter algumas informações que ajudarão a diagnosticar o problema, mas como já falhamos, algo está definitivamente errado e isso pode falhou. Versão do servidor: 10.2. 2-MariaDB key_buffer_size = 16777216 read_buffer_size = 262144 max_used_connections = 0 max_threads = 1001 thread_count = 0 É possível que o mysqld possa usar até key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size) * max_threads = 787136 K bytes de memória Espero que esteja ok; se não, diminua algumas variáveis ​​na equação. Ponteiro de thread: 0x0x0 Tentando backtrace. Você pode usar as seguintes informações para descobrir onde o mysqld morreu. Se você não vê nenhuma mensagem depois disso, algo deu errado [Nota] InnoDB: Carregando buffer pool (s) de C: \ xampp \ mysql \ data \ ib_buffer_pool 2018-11-12 14:23:57 6300 [Nota] 'FEEDBACK 'plugin está desativado. 2018-11-12 14:23:57 6300 [Nota] Soquete do servidor criado no IP: '::'. 2018-11-12 14:23:57 1828 [Nota] InnoDB: Buffer pool (s) de carga concluída em 181112 14: 23:57 mysqld.exe! my_parameter_handler () [my_init.c: 256] mysqld.exe! raise () [winsig.c: 587] mysqld.exe! abort () [abort.c: 75] kernel32.dll! HeapFree () mysqld.exe! free () [free.c: 51] A página de manual emhttp://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contém informações que devem ajudá-lo a descobrir o que está causando a falha.

Comment: Tinha backup desse banco? Esse tipo de erro tem cara de não ser recuperável de nenhuma forma.

Comment: Tenho sim, tive que reinstalar o Mysql, mas queria saber se tem como recuperar ...(Como eu estou com o MariaDB no xampp e por padrão da versão do xampp mais atual vem com a versão 10.1, para fazer o upgrade para versão 10.2 é um trabalho bem chatinho)

Comment: tem um comando de repair table tenta fazer ele as vezes funciona.

Comment: o problema que depois deste problema, eu não consigo mais logar no mysql, por consequência não posso rodar nenhum comando...